# Everywhere existence of marginals

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ be a (joint) probability density function which satisfies $f(x,y)>0$ for *all* $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}$.

What is a necessary and sufficient condition under which the marginal $$ f^y (y)\equiv\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,y) dx $$
exists *for all* $y\in \mathbb{R}$?

*Comments:*

- because of Fubini, I'm pretty sure $f^y$ exists almost-everywhere in $y$. However, I don't see how continuity or smoothness of $f$ would guarantee existence everywhere.
- I believe that on a compact domain (e.g., $f:[0,1]^2 \to \mathbb{R}$), Lipschitz/Holder continuity of $f$ is sufficient to guarantee existence of the marginals everywhere.

** [cross posted from MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4876267/161591), after a week+ with no comments

Comment: In what non-tautological terms do you want the "necessary and sufficient condition" stated?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Maybe there isn't, but hopefully "if $f$ is smooth" or something like that

Comment: but even a counter example would be welcome

Comment: But the smoothness of $f$ is clearly not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Assumptions such as smoothness will not guarantee this. Consider $f(x,y)=\varphi((1+y^2)x)$ with a $\varphi\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$ with $\varphi> 0$, $\varphi(0)=1$, $\int\varphi = 1/\pi$. Then $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R^2)$,
$$
\int dy\int dx f(x,y)= \frac{1}{\pi}\int \frac{dy}{1+y^2} =1 ,
$$
so $f$ is a density, but $f(0,y)=1\notin L^1$.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great point. So back to @losif pinelis' point, there's really only a "tautological" necessary and sufficient condition for everywhere existence of the marginals?

Comment: @AmirSagiv: Yes, that is my impression also.